# how can i used conditional to re assign and declare new variable

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment

Hello guy I actually thought something like this will  work in javascript. i declared this variable and i wanted to redeclare and reassign it again but with a condition if it was previously undefined, the code should be ignored, but its like am getting it all wrong.Please take a look at what i did.

```
         var car = 'BMW';
         console.log(car);//returns BMW
         if (car === undefined)
         var car = 'Saab';
         console.log(car)// returns Saab
```

i thought it should return BMW. Am wrong right?
Guys what  i wanted to do, is to have javascript ignore the second assignment of Saab to the car variable, because i thought that the condition specifies that the value of saab should be re-assigned to the car variable only if it is undefined or not defined. But it is defined, yet saab still print out, is the if statement actually wrong, because as far i am concern, I didn't achieve what I intended.

Comment: Where/how did you test this? It logs "BMW" two times, not "Saab".

Comment: 1) Don't use `var` on the same variable more than once. 2) The `var` keyword has *function* scope, not *block* scope. Use ES6 `let`/`const` for block scope.

Comment: It doesn't log "saab"... as @str asked,"How did you test this?", Can you show the output in fiddle?

Comment: fiddle? how do i use that?

Comment: check out this link https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I get only BMW in console for two times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
         var car = 'BMW';
         console.log(car);//returns BMW
         if (car === undefined){
                var car = 'Saab';

         }
         console.log(car)// returns Saab
```

You can replace `var car = 'Saab';`with `car = 'Saab';` to create the variable car in the global scope.

Comment: I actually intend to see if i could contril the flow, by making javascript ignore the re assingment car is defined. I i expected to see BMW like before and no Saab. thanks

Comment: yea thanks it actually worked as intended with the ddition of the {} how so.

Answer (score 0):

Like in most languages, you do not declare the variable multiple times. You can however re-assign as much as you'd like.

```
     var car = 'BMW';
     console.log(car);//returns BMW
     if (car === undefined)
     car = 'Saab';
     console.log(car)// returns Saab
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".